# Core API: AttributeError: module 'click' has no attribute 'style'

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, django-rest-framework, core-api

I am a beginner in Django REST framework and while going through [this part of the tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/7-schemas-and-client-libraries/) I faced and error. I installed `coreapi` and did the desired changes to the code but when I try to run the server, I face this problem:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f6220bd6268>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/atenagm/tutorial/tutorial/tutorial/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
url(r'^', include('snippets.urls')),
File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/atenagm/tutorial/tutorial/snippets/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
from snippets import views
File "/home/atenagm/tutorial/tutorial/snippets/views.py", line 2, in <module>
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer, UserSerializer
File "/home/atenagm/tutorial/tutorial/snippets/serializers.py", line 1, in <module>
from rest_framework import serializers
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 30, in <module>
from rest_framework.compat import JSONField as ModelJSONField
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/compat.py", line 170, in <module>
import coreapi
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/coreapi/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from coreapi import auth, codecs, exceptions, transports, utils
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/coreapi/auth.py", line 1, in <module>
from coreapi.utils import domain_matches
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/coreapi/utils.py", line 2, in <module>
from coreapi.compat import string_types, text_type, urlparse, _TemporaryFileWrapper
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/coreapi/compat.py", line 56, in <module>
console_style = click.style
AttributeError: module 'click' has no attribute 'style'
```

I couldn't find any solution to this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Same problem here! Have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Twimnox I couldn't come up with any solutions myself. I just skipped that part of the tutorial :( But I'm still looking for solutions

Comment: Solved! my problem was that I had a python package named "click" which was interfering...  Maybe you have one too, or some of your libraries have a package "click" too.

Comment: @Twimnox Ah!  I named my testing file `click.py` to try to get Click's MWEs to work.  Changing to `myclick.py` fixed it!